# Error when passing PHP array to js

Tags: javascript, php

I have this array (`$test`) in PHP

```
array (size=4)
  1 => string 'test1@mail.example' (length=17)
  2 => string 'test2@mail.example' (length=17)
  3 => string 'test3@mail.example' (length=17)
  4 => string 'test4@mail.example' (length=17)
```

And want to pass it to javascript. My goal is to use this in a AJAX query.

So I did the following

```
var test = "<?php echo json_encode($test); ?>";
$.post("../path/to/file.php",
{
  test: test,
},
function(data,status)
{ 
  ...
});
```

But the following is triggering everytime

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
var test = "{"1":"test1@mail.example","2":"test1@mail.
```

Comment: Maybe a missing semicolon after `var test = "<?php echo json_encode($test); ?>"` ? Your code example is not complete, there is no `var input` as stated in you error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't enclose the json output in quotes. It's unecessary:

```
var test = <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>;
```

json_encode() will already be adding any necessary `"` characters, and your extra `"` are breaking the syntax, e.g.

php:

```
$foo = 'ab"c';

json_encode($foo) -> "ab\"c";
```

js:

```
var test1 =  <?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>;
var test2 = "<?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>";
```

which comes out as:

```
var test1 = "ab\"c";      // this line is ok
var test2 = ""ab\"c"";  // this line is fubar
            ^--start string
             ^--end string
              ^^---undeclared/undefined variable
```